# Web application: Hold large object between requests

Tags: python

I'm working on a web application related to genome searching. This application makes use of this [suffix tree library](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/suds/cst/) through Cython bindings. Objects of this type are large (hundreds of MB up to ~10GB) and take as long to load from disk as it takes to process them in response to a page request. I'm looking for a way to load several of these objects once on server boot and then use them for all page requests.

I have tried using a remote manager / client setup using the multiprocessing module, modeled after [this demo](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager), but it fails when the client connects with an error message that says the object is not picklable.

Comment: That depends largely on which HTTP server you're using and what frameworks you're using… Can you let us know?

Comment: Page requests are currently handled by Drupal on LAMP with jobs created in response to a form submission. There's currently no persistently running python process. I'm open to changing that though.

Comment: Wait… So if your requests are handled by Drupal, where does Python come in? Do you want the Drupal app to make a connection to a Python server to do the processing?

Comment: Drupal handles the web pages and when a user submits a job request PHP starts a Python script that does the actual genome processing. It wasn't really my decision, I got passed the project from someone else.

Comment: Ah, well, take a look at my answer and let me know how it works. You might also want to look into using something like http://ask.github.com/celery/ (and http://www.toforge.com/2011/01/run-celery-tasks-from-php/ )

Comment: I'm currently testing Flask and will get back to you. The goal is to set up something like Celery next, but first they want a proof of concept up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest writing a small Flask (or even raw WSGI… But it's probably simpler to use Flask, as it will be easier to get up and running quickly) application which loads the genome database then exposes a simple API. Something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
database = load_database()

@app.route('/get_genomes')
def get_genomes():
    return database.all_genomes()

app.run(debug=True)
```

Or, you know, something a bit more sensible.

Also, if you need to be handling more than one request at a time (I believe that `app.run` will only handle one at a time), start by threading… And if that's too slow, you can `os.fork()` *after* the database is loaded and run multiple request handlers from there (that way they will all share the same database in memory).

Comment: Sorry, I'm now trying to pair this with a task queue and running into issues.

https://gist.github.com/2b94198bc0b8ec631186

This won't work as Pyres can't handle job class that are defined in the same file as jobs are enqueued, but if I move the job class to a different module I don't know how to keep access to the globals from the main file. Using a static perform method seems to be a requirement and arguments passed to it need to be serializable, which the tree isn't.

Comment: Create a simple package (`mkdir otsf_web; touch otsf_web/__init__.py`), then create three files: `matrix.py` (which will load the scoring matrix, and whatever else), `web.py` (which will have the Flask-specific stuff) and `tasks.py` (which will have the tasks). Run the web server with a fourth script, from the same directory which contains the `otsf_web` directory: `from otsf_web.web import app; app.run()`

Comment: @DavidWolever Is this method thread-safe? Does it work with different concurrency models (threading, forking, gevent etc.) under a server like gunicorn?

Comment: Yep, this method is just as thread safe as the underlying data structure. For example, if the underlying data was entirely read only then this would be entirely thread safe. It works identically across all concurrency models, with the caveats normal to each one.